# Security roles members in MS CRM 4.0

Tags: security, dynamics-crm, crm

Is there a way to see users that have certain security role assigned?

I'm looking for a hint that I missed something or a tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also an Administrative Report available and this is probably the easiest way to find which users are have which security roles.

You can find it here: Workplace / Reports / View: Administrative Reports / **User Summary**

Answer (score 1):

Set up an advanced find like the following:

[image: Advanced find to show users that have the System Administrator role]

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted it and replaced it with advertising. This has left your answer as being very low quality. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check in application by going to settings --> Administration--> Users -->"Select User"--> Roles. Roles will display for the selected user.

If you want to **add or remove roles** for any user that can be done through Admin Privileged Users.